# How do I send customer data from twilio to stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, twilio

I'm using Twilio to allow my customers to pay automatically over the phone via  to stripe. I followed this tutorial: [Is there a way to enter dollars/cents via DTMF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62324697/is-there-a-way-to-enter-dollars-cents-via-dtmf)

The issue I'm running into is how do I send the "phone number" as a "customer" into stripe? The reason I want this is to be able to see who bought what and how many times etc. Currently, they are all coming into stripe as unknown/guest.

My only success has been (I'm using the studio) entering {{trigger.call.From}} into the "payment description". That still doesn't solve the issue fully though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my flow code:

```
{
  "description": "A New Flow",
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Trigger",
      "type": "trigger",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "received_message_forward",
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "next": "gather_1",
          "event": "incomingCall"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingConversationMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingRequest"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingParent"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "gather_1",
      "type": "gather-input-on-call",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "function_1",
          "event": "keypress"
        },
        {
          "event": "speech"
        },
        {
          "next": "gather_1",
          "event": "timeout"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "voice": "man",
        "speech_timeout": "auto",
        "offset": {
          "x": 30,
          "y": 270
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "finish_on_key": "#",
        "say": "Welcome and thank you for calling the donation line. Please enter the amount you wish to donate, then press pound. To enter with cents use the star key. for example to enter $18.50, press one eight star five zero.",
        "language": "en-US",
        "stop_gather": true,
        "gather_language": "en",
        "profanity_filter": "true",
        "timeout": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "function_1",
      "type": "run-function",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "confirm_donation_amount",
          "event": "success"
        },
        {
          "event": "fail"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": -60,
          "y": 530
        },
        "parameters": [
          {
            "value": "{{widgets.gather_1.Digits}}",
            "key": "amount"
          }
        ],
        "url": "https://sand-pointer-5043.twil.io/pay_from_exchange"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "say_play_2",
      "type": "say-play",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "audioComplete"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "voice": "man",
        "offset": {
          "x": -60,
          "y": 840
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "say": "You entered ${{widgets.function_1.body}}",
        "language": "en-US"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "pay_1",
      "type": "capture-payments",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "say_play_3",
          "event": "success"
        },
        {
          "next": "say_play_4",
          "event": "maxFailedAttempts"
        },
        {
          "next": "say_play_4",
          "event": "providerError"
        },
        {
          "next": "say_play_4",
          "event": "payInterrupted"
        },
        {
          "next": "say_play_4",
          "event": "hangup"
        },
        {
          "next": "say_play_4",
          "event": "validationError"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "security_code": true,
        "offset": {
          "x": -70,
          "y": 1140
        },
        "max_attempts": 2,
        "payment_connector": "",
        "payment_amount": "{{widgets.function_1.body}}",
        "description": "{{trigger.call.From}} via Twilio",
        "currency": "usd",
        "language": "en-US",
        "postal_code": "false",
        "payment_token_type": "reusable",
        "timeout": 5,
        "valid_card_types": [
          "visa",
          "master-card",
          "amex",
          "discover"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "say_play_3",
      "type": "say-play",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "send_success_message_1",
          "event": "audioComplete"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "voice": "man",
        "offset": {
          "x": -185,
          "y": 1433
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "say": "Your donation of ${{widgets.function_1.body}} was successful, Thank you.",
        "language": "en-US"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "say_play_4",
      "type": "say-play",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "send_fail_message_1",
          "event": "audioComplete"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "voice": "man",
        "offset": {
          "x": 190,
          "y": 1456
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "say": "There was an error with your donation. Please verify your details and call back to try again. Thanks!",
        "language": "en-US"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "send_success_message_1",
      "type": "send-message",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "sent"
        },
        {
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": -100,
          "y": 1700
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "to": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "body": "Your donation of ${{widgets.function_1.body}} was successful, Thank you!."
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "send_fail_message_1",
      "type": "send-message",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "sent"
        },
        {
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 250,
          "y": 1700
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "to": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "body": "There was an error with your donation. Please verify your details and call back to try again. Thanks!"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "confirm_donation_amount",
      "type": "gather-input-on-call",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "split_2",
          "event": "keypress"
        },
        {
          "event": "speech"
        },
        {
          "next": "confirm_donation_amount",
          "event": "timeout"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "number_of_digits": 1,
        "speech_timeout": "auto",
        "offset": {
          "x": 420,
          "y": 530
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "finish_on_key": "#",
        "say": "You entered ${{widgets.function_1.body}}. Press 1 to confirm, or press 2 to enter a different amount.",
        "stop_gather": true,
        "gather_language": "en",
        "profanity_filter": "true",
        "timeout": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "split_2",
      "type": "split-based-on",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "confirm_donation_amount",
          "event": "noMatch"
        },
        {
          "next": "pay_1",
          "event": "match",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "friendly_name": "If value equal_to 1",
              "arguments": [
                "{{widgets.confirm_donation_amount.Digits}}"
              ],
              "type": "equal_to",
              "value": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "next": "gather_1",
          "event": "match",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "friendly_name": "If value equal_to 2",
              "arguments": [
                "{{widgets.confirm_donation_amount.Digits}}"
              ],
              "type": "equal_to",
              "value": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "input": "{{widgets.confirm_donation_amount.Digits}}",
        "offset": {
          "x": 430,
          "y": 800
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "received_message_forward",
      "type": "send-message",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "sent"
        },
        {
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": -300,
          "y": 250
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "to": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "body": "Thanks for texting the Donation line. To donate, please call us on this same number. We do not accept donations via text."
      }
    }
  ],
  "initial_state": "Trigger",
  "flags": {
    "allow_concurrent_calls": true
  }
}
```

Here is the function:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

const amount = event.amount;
const convert = amount.replace('*', '.');

    callback(null, convert);
};
```

Comment: Could you share more code?  Some examples of what you have tried and what the outcome was would be very helpful.

Comment: Once user's phone number is verified, you can use https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create this API to create stripe customer.

Comment: @DrashtiKheni Can that be done from the studio in tiwlio?

Comment: What do you mean with studio?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni twilio studio. It’s a drag and drop flow instead of just functions.

Comment: @JayF you can use the Studio Make HTTP request widget to hit any of the Stripe endpoints! Or you could convert the `create a customer in Stripe` curl request to Node.js and put it in a Twilio Function/run that Twilio Function from Studio

Comment: @lizziepika How will stripe know to assign the payment to the newly created customer?

Comment: @JayF isn't that just `update` a customer in the Stripe docs above?